# Sierpinski's Carpet Python Error using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This isn't a dublicate because I'm trying to fix the error in my code, not how to do the problem itself. I found code that says it draws Sierpinski's Carpet in Python using turtle, but only gives me a giant error message. I get an error talking about turtle's Display and name not given. I've never used turtle so I wanted to try this. Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    wigs = turtle.Turtle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3812, in __init__
    Turtle._screen = Screen()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3662, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3678, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 434, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2261, in __init__    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
import math
t = turtle.Turtle()
def s(n, l):

    if n == 0: # stop conditions

        # draw filled rectangle

        t.color('black')
        t.begin_fill()
        for _ in range (4):
            t.forward(l)
            t.left(90)
        t.end_fill()

    else: # recursion

        # around center point create 8 smalles rectangles.
        # create two rectangles on every side 
        # so you have to repeat it four times

        for _ in range(4):
            # first rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            t.forward(l/3)

            # second rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            t.forward(l/3)

            # go to next corner
            t.forward(l/3)
            t.left(90)

        # update screen
        t.update()

# --- main ---    

# stop updating screen (to make it faster)
t.tracer(0) 

# start
try:
  s(4, 400)
except:
  print("This loop has reached it's max callback")
# event loop 
t.done()
```

If this is a bad way to make the Carpet then please show me a different way. I really need help.
I really need help as soon as possible, please!!

Comment: We generally expect a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Had you provided one, you would see that the problem is outside your program: your environment doesn't provide the required `DISPLAY` value, specifying the graphic output device.  In short, you haven't told it where to find a device on which it can draw.

Comment: I use Repl for desktop and chromebook. What display value should I use?

Comment: You'll have to take that up with your operating system and system configuration.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is *not* for time-critical problems.  Such things need to be posted to an appropriate site, such as your class's discussion forum.  Ask a classmate to print their DISPLAY value, and set yours accordingly.  This is a problem in your set-up, likely some oversight in your login initialization, or perhaps some application corrupted the value.

Comment: If you're on Linux, try `echo $DISPLAY` to see the value.  You can look up how to set environment variables.  You can also try posting to the Stack Exchange "superuser" group.

Comment: can you provide an example on how to put that in my code? Like I said, first time using turtle

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site or a replacement for existing on-line resources.  Please see the posting guidelines and explain where you're stuck with the available resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code, as I found this elsewhere on StackOverflow an I will post it here. (Working fine on Windows 10 computer with python 3.7.4)

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def s(n, l):

    if n == 0: # stop conditions

        # draw filled rectangle
        turtle.pencolor("green")
        turtle.fillcolor('black')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        for _ in range (4):
            turtle.forward(l)
            turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()

    else: # recursion

        # around center point create 8 smalles rectangles.
        # create two rectangles on every side 
        # so you have to repeat it four times

        for _ in range(4):
            # first rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            turtle.forward(l/3)

            # second rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            turtle.forward(l/3)

            # go to next corner
            turtle.forward(l/3)
            turtle.left(90)

        # update screen
        turtle.update()

# --- main ---    

# stop updating screen (to make it faster)
turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.penup()
turtle.setx(-480)
turtle.sety(-480)
turtle.pendown()
# start
s(5, 960)
turtle.speed(0)
# event loop
turtle.done()
```

s(5,960) means it makes 5 iterations and the square is 960 pixels wide)